# PHP Looping through PDO query results

Tags: php, oop, pdo, foreach

I am new to OOP and PDO. Thanks in advance for any help!

I'm having a problem with looping out my SQL query results to the page.

Here is my notes.inc.php

```
$note->tulosta_notet('notes');
```

in class Note I have the method

```
public function tulosta_notet($table) {
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM " . $table . "";
        $result = $this->_db->query($sql);

        echo "<br />";
        print_r($result);

        foreach ($result as $row) {
            print $row["id"] . "-" . $row["note_text"] ."<br/>";
        }
    }
```

I am getting the right results with the `print_r($result);`

So the query is correct, I just can't get the rows print right way to the page.

Here is the output of print_r($result);

```
DB Object ( [_pdo:DB:private] => PDO Object ( )
 [_query:DB:private] => PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM notes ) 
[_error:DB:private] => [_results:DB:private] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object (
 [id] => 1 
[created] => 2015-03-08 13:50:43 [edited] => 2015-03-08 14:50:43 
[note_text] => hei hei moi moi hei hei hei [
user_id] => 1 ) 

[1] => stdClass Object ( 
[id] => 2 
[created] => 2015-03-08 14:23:55
 [edited] => 2015-03-08 15:23:55 
[note_text] => text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 [user_id] => 1 ) 
) [_count:DB:private] => 2 )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Should I rather do the looping in notes.inc.php, what should I return from the tulosta_notet() to get it work ?
Thanks

-E

**here is the var_dump($this->_db);exit;**

```
object(DB)#3 (5) { 
["_pdo":"DB":private]=> object(PDO)#4 (0) { } 
["_query":"DB":private]=> object(PDOStatement)#9 (1) {
 ["queryString"]=> string(28) "SELECT * FROM notes" 
} 
["_error":"DB":private]=> bool(false)
 ["_results":"DB":private]=> array(2) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (5) { 
["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
["created"]=> string(19) "2015-03-08 13:50:43" 
["edited"]=> string(19) "2015-03-08 14:50:43" 
["note_text"]=> string(27) "hei hei moi moi hei hei hei" 
["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
} 

[1]=> object(stdClass)#10 (5) {
 ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
["created"]=> string(19) "2015-03-08 14:23:55" 
["edited"]=> string(19) "2015-03-08 15:23:55" 
["note_text"]=> string(90) "text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text " ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
} 
} ["_count":"DB":private]=> int(2) }
```

query() in class DB

```
 public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {

            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param) {
                    // echo $param;
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                    // echo $x."<br>";
                }
            }

            if($this->_query->execute()) {
                echo "Success";
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: What is $this->_db? Is it a Object of class 'PDO' or is it some sort of wrapper?

Comment: You are trying to loop over $results as an array, but it isn't an array. It's an object holding _query, _error and _results params. You probably need some fetch / fetchAll call after doing the query. It's kinda hard to suggest code as it seems you aren't using the native pdo class, look up the documentation for whatever db class you are using.

Comment: added var_dump results to orginal message. DB is a separate class where I have the query(). I will add its insides to the orginal message too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 'query' method, you use a fluent interface (return `$this` returns the current object). As a result when you `print_r()`, an object is printed.

Modify your query method or use a fetch function like:

```
public function tulosta_notet($table) {   

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table;
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
    $res = $stmt->execute();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($res); $i++) {
        print $res[$i]["id"] . "-" . $res[$i]["note_text"] ."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: See query(); what i added to my orginal message. I'm doing both execute() and prepare() inside it. 

$this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

Comment: I saw that, it's not that you don't use those commands, I suppose that it is that you echo the whole object. return $this, at your function returning the whole object. This is called a "fluent interface". I cannot check your code but if you have an error, you have to modify somehow your 'query' method

Comment: Thanks Nikos for help. I actually made two more methods to solve this.